# 17.10 Unplug/Replug mouse/kb doesn't get detected

Tags: keyboard, mouse

So there's a weird issue happening. After the upgrade from 17.04 to 17.10, when I unplug my mouse and keyboard and replug them back in, they do not always get detected.

Running lsusb does not list them. I only seem to get them back after I restart the computer (which also hangs and I have to hold down the power button, but that's another issue).

Any ideas about how to fix this? I don't remember this being a problem with 17.04. Is it another kernel problem?

This **doesn't always happen** and I can't figure out what causes it when it happens.

I'm trying a DELL standard wired keyboard and a Logitech G700s (both wired and wireless)

Here's an lsusb output from when everything works, if that's of any use:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1770:ff00  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:980a Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 046d:c07c Logitech, Inc. M-R0017 [G700s Rechargeable Gaming Mouse]
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 046d:c531 Logitech, Inc. C-U0007 [Unifying Receiver]
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2a70:9011  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```